# What is the classification head of a hugging face AutoModelForTokenClassification Model

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, text-classification

I am a beginner to hugging face and transformers and have been trying to figure out what is the classification head of the AutoModelForTokenClassification? Is is just a BiLSTM-CRF layer or is it something else?

In general where do find details about the heads of these AutoModels?

I have tried looking into the docs but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AutoModel* is not pytorch model implementation, it is an implemented [factory pattern](https://realpython.com/factory-method-python/). That means it returns an instance of a different class depending on the provided parameters. For example:

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForTokenClassification

m = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
print(type(m))
```

Output:

```
<class 'transformers.models.roberta.modeling_roberta.RobertaForTokenClassification'>
```

You can check the head either with the [official documentation of the class](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.27.2/src/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py#L1360) or with [parameters](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.parameters):

```
m.parameters
```

Output:

```
<bound method Module.parameters of RobertaForTokenClassification(
  (roberta): RobertaModel(
    (embeddings): RobertaEmbeddings(
      (word_embeddings): Embedding(50265, 768, padding_idx=1)
      (position_embeddings): Embedding(514, 768, padding_idx=1)
      (token_type_embeddings): Embedding(1, 768)
      (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
      (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    )
    (encoder): RobertaEncoder(
      (layer): ModuleList(
        (0): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
<... truncated ...>
        (11): RobertaLayer(
          (attention): RobertaAttention(
            (self): RobertaSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): RobertaSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): RobertaIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            (intermediate_act_fn): GELUActivation()
          )
          (output): RobertaOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
  (classifier): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2, bias=True)
)>
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for. The official documentation has for these specific models(Like RoBERTa), but I was looking for the general AutoModelForTokenClassification's architecture, but this solution also answers that. Thanks!